# C++ - How to count how many compares it took the program to find a value in the binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Below is the code I use to 1) extract numbers from a text file and save them into an array; 2) use the array as “input” and import the numbers from the array into a binary tree; 3) search through the binary tree to find user-input values, if found, output “Value Found”, if not found, output “Value not found.”

The code works perfectly fine. But I am struggling on the last part. I have to make the program output how many compares it took to find (or not find) each value in the binary tree.

```
#include<iostream>
#include  <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//define the struct of a binary tree

typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    node * pLeft;
    node * pRight;
    node(int val = 0)
    {
        value = val;
        pRight = NULL;
        pLeft = NULL;
    }
}node;


//decide insertion location for each value imported from the array
void insert(node*& pRoot, int val)
{
    if (pRoot == NULL)
    {
        //insertion place found
        pRoot = new node;
        pRoot->pRight = NULL;
        pRoot->pLeft = NULL;
        pRoot->value = val;
    }
    else if (val < pRoot->value)
        insert(pRoot->pLeft, val);
    else
        insert(pRoot->pRight, val);
}

//pass in value from arrary to the binary tree
node * getBST(int * arr, int size)
{
    node * pRoot = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        insert(pRoot, arr[i]);
    return pRoot;
}

//look through the binary tree to find the user-input value 
void Retrieve(node* pRoot, int value)
{
        if (pRoot == NULL)
        {
            bool found = false;
            cout << "Value not found" << endl;
        }
        else if (value < pRoot->value)
        {
            Retrieve(pRoot->pLeft, value);
        }
        else if (value > pRoot->value)
        {
            Retrieve(pRoot->pRight, value);
        }
        else
        {
            value = pRoot->value;
            bool found = true;
            cout << "Value found" << endl;
        }

}

int main()
{
    ifstream file("5 Random Numbers.txt");
    if (file.is_open())                    //open the file
    {
        int arr[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)     //put numbers in the file into the array
        {
            file >> arr[i];
        }

        node * pRoot = getBST(arr, 5);   //convert array to binary tree; 5 is the size   

        for (int i = 0;i < 3; ++i)     //ask user to enter 3 numbers, then search these numbers in the binary tree
        {
            int userValue;
            cout << "Enter an integer to search: ";
            cin >> userValue;
            Retrieve(pRoot, userValue);
        }


        cout << endl;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Right now, the Retrieve function can only show whether the value it's found or not. But, I alo need it to print out how many compares it took to find the value.

For example, if the text file contains five numbers “123 15 392 88 731”, and I enter the number “88” to search, it should take the program 3 compares to find the number in the binary tree. I want to the program to print out something like “It took 3 compares.”

If I enter number “999”. “999” doesn’t exist in the binary tree, but it still took the program 3 compares to reach that conclusion, so the program should print out “It took 3 compares.”
I tried to add a for-loop into the Retrieve function, but somehow it didn’t work out…Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: You could add a 3rd parameter which is number of compares, add +1 on each call. And print it under `value found`. Alternatively, you could also maintain a static counter.

Comment: Side note: C++ has no need for the old `typdef struct x {...} x;` trick. By the time C++ showed up C programmers had been doing it for decades, so C++ baked it in. All you need is `struct x{...};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `depth` parameter to your function and increment it for each level of the tree.

```
void Retrieve(node* pRoot, int value, int depth)
{
        if (pRoot == NULL)
        {
            bool found = false;
            cout << "Value not found" << endl;
        }
        else if (value < pRoot->value)
        {
            Retrieve(pRoot->pLeft, value, ++depth);
        }
        else if (value > pRoot->value)
        {
            Retrieve(pRoot->pRight, value, ++depth);
        }
        else
        {
            value = pRoot->value;
            bool found = true;
            cout << "Value found" << depth << endl;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function insert can be simplified taking into account the definition of the constructor of the struct node.

```
void insert(node*& pRoot, int val)
{
    if (pRoot == NULL)
    {
        //insertion place found
        pRoot = new node( val );
    }
    else if ( value < pRoot->value)
        insert(pRoot->pLeft, val);
    else
        insert(pRoot->pRight, val);
}
```

The function Retrieve shall not output anything. It shall return a boolean value either true or false. It is the caller of the function that based on the return value of the function decides what message to output. The function can be implemented the following way

```
//look through the binary tree to find the user-input value 
bool Retrieve( const node* pRoot, int value, size_t &n )
{
        if ( pRoot == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if ( ++n, value < pRoot->value )
        {
            return Retrieve( pRoot->pLeft, value, n );
        }
        else if ( ++n, value > pRoot->value )
        {
            return Retrieve(pRoot->pRight, value, n );
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
}
```

Before calling the function the argument that corresponds to the third parameter should be set to zero if you want to count the number of comparisons in a single call of the function..

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int value;
    node * pLeft;
    node * pRight;
};

void insert( node* &pRoot, int value )
{
    if ( pRoot == nullptr )
    {
        pRoot = new node { value, nullptr, nullptr };
    }
    else if ( value < pRoot->value )
    {
        insert( pRoot->pLeft, value );
    }
    else
    {
        insert( pRoot->pRight, value );
    }
}

bool Retrieve( const node* pRoot, int value, size_t &n )
{
    if ( pRoot == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if ( ++n, value < pRoot->value )
    {
        return Retrieve( pRoot->pLeft, value, n );
    }
    else if ( ++n, value > pRoot->value )
    {
        return Retrieve(pRoot->pRight, value, n );
    }
     else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    node *pRoot = nullptr;
    int a[] = { 123, 15, 392, 88, 731 };

    for ( const auto item : a ) insert( pRoot, item );

    size_t n = 0;
    int value = 88;

    if ( Retrieve( pRoot, value, n ) )
    {
        std::cout << value << " is found after " << n << " comparisons\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << value << " is not found after " << n << " comparisons\n";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
88 is found after 5 comparisons
```

Pay attention to that there are `5` comparisons and not `3` as you wrote in the question.

Indeed. The first comparison with the value of the root node that is 123. Then the second comparison with the value of the left node with value 15. There are two comparisons in this case corresponding to the number of if statements that were executed

```
    else if ( ++n, value < pRoot->value )
    {
        return Retrieve( pRoot->pLeft, value, n );
    }
    else if ( ++n, value > pRoot->value )
    {
        return Retrieve(pRoot->pRight, value, n );
    }
```

And then to determine that the current node contains exactly the value 88 there are again two comparisons are performed with the value of the current node

```
    else if ( ++n, value < pRoot->value )
    {
        return Retrieve( pRoot->pLeft, value, n );
    }
    else if ( ++n, value > pRoot->value )
    {
        return Retrieve(pRoot->pRight, value, n );
    }
     else
    {
        return true;
    }
```

So the correct answer is `5` comparisons. As for the number 3 then it is not the number of comparisons. It is a number of recursive calls.

If you want to count the number of recursive calls of the function instead of the number of comparisons then change the function the following way

```
bool Retrieve( const node* pRoot, int value, size_t &n )
{
    ++n;

    if ( pRoot == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if ( value < pRoot->value )
    {
        return Retrieve( pRoot->pLeft, value, n );
    }
    else if ( value > pRoot->value )
    {
        return Retrieve(pRoot->pRight, value, n );
    }
     else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

In this case indeed the number of recursive calls of the function (not the number of comparisons) will be equal to `3`.

Using this approach you can for example count the total number of comparisons for several calls of the function.